Configure C# dev kit build output to show errors in red
VS Code's terminal is useful in the sense that you can directly navigate to the errors from the build output, however since everything is colored white you have to spend time to actually glance through the output and find the error. I tried adding explicit color to VS Code terminal using:
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "terminal.foreground": "#FFFFFF",
        "terminal.errorForeground": "#BF1A1A"
    }

But the build output does not seem to inherit the terminal configuration.
Is there a way to do this?
